# &shy; hyphenation not working in Gutenberg editor

Tags: html, block-editor

Thanks to the German language, I happen to have some really long words in my WordPress 5.4.1 content. 
I need to decide **where exactly to hyphenate**, as the standard hyphenation is dumb.

If I enter `Wachstums&shy;förderung` in the Gutenberg block editor in a headline (e.g. h2), I do not get the expected `Wachstums-förderung` in the website - it outputs `Wachstums&shy;förderung`.
(This does work, though, in the page title, outside of the block editor)!

My web search yielded an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12872
It is open since Dec 2018 and nothing seems to happen soon :-/

Does anybody have an idea, how to solve that problem? (No, putting a hard dash is not an option.)

Comment: Maybe copy and pasting a soft-hyphen character might work? WordPress should store it and re-render it correctly, even if it might not encode it as an entity.

Comment: Clever idea, @rup but I can't manage to copy it - I am not able to mark/select it in the browser :-/

Comment: There are a lots of services where you can copy this character. Just google a little :)
E.g. https://unicode-explorer.com/c/00AD

Answer (score 2):

You can change the block to "edit as html" via "more options" and set the soft hyphen, then switch back to "Edit visualy".

Comment: This does not work, as TinyMCE is filtering out the &shy; entity amongst others (in Gutenberg for example)

Comment: Do you have tested it? It's filtered out in the editor, but if you check the frontend you'll see that the &shy; ist placed in html.

Comment: Confirm this works. This is the best option in my opinion. Hyphen always shows in editor, but only when needed on the frontend

Answer (score 2):

With the 'new' Gutenberg editor the previously working solution using the *tiny_mce_before_init* hook does not work anymore, but there is the possibility to define a new shortcode in your theme / plugin as a workaround.

**Solution for Gutenberg**

```
add_shortcode('shy', 'my_shy_shortcode');
function my_shy_shortcode($atts) {
    return '&shy;';
}
```

This simply adds a new shortcode to WordPress with a *&shy;* entity as output, so you can just write [shy] anywhere in your text and it will be translated to the HTML entity;

There is currently no 'cleaner' solution and it seems that none is planned, at least not before 5.8 (Github [issue 1](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12872), [issue 2](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23509))

**Solution for the Classic Editor (no Gutenberg)**

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
    $initArray['entities'] = 'shy';

    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

This should prevent TinyMCE from filtering out the shy tag, for more information on how to fine-tune this and keep other entities as well read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29261339/826194

Answer (score 1):

Here is a invisible soft hyphen for you to copy: "­".

Unlike the HTML entity `&shy;` which gets filtered out the second time you edit your content, I am able to insert the invisible soft hyphen character.
Unfortunately you can visually not tell when it's present. You can identify a invisible character because the cursor won't move when you hit arrow key.

I am using macOS and configured the [fn] key on my keyboard to show the character/emoji picker. There you can search for "soft hyphen"; it appears as a normal hyphen, but when you double click it, it will be inserted into you document.